# My php files isn't working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

i installed php,mysql,apache on linux And i created info.php at /var/www/html/info.php and i enter http://localhost/info.php , i see

```
<?php
    echo ("deneme");
?>
```

[image]
My page isn't working..

But i enter http://localhost/index.php , dashboard is working.

Comment: Make sure you have installed PHP properly. Seems your code is not being executed. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)  will help you

Comment: Looks like your web server is serving info.php as plain/text while index.php is correctly proxied to the fastcgi server; check your web server's configuration.

Comment: Also, welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and learn how to create a [mcve], cheers!